# FrameLayouts not shown when used with Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I would like to test out using fragment manager to replace fragments dynamically. In the main layout, under the parent liner layout, I have 3 layouts, one child linear layout and 2 child frame layouts. The idea is to use a button in the first child linear layout to swap fragments in the 3rd frame layouts.

The issue I am seeing: when the application is loaded, only the child linear layout shows up on the screen; the fragments and their frame layout container is not visible. Can someone tell whether I am doing anything wrong here? There are no particular errors in the LogCat...

I tried to tweak the weight parameter for child layouts to resolve this issue, but without too much success.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Here are the activities classes:

[MainActivity.java]

```
package com.jiao.android.todolist;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements NewItemFragment.OnNewItemAddedListener {

private ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
private ArrayList<String> todoItems;
private ArrayAdapter<String> aa2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Get reference to the Fragments
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    ToDoListFragment todoListFragment = (ToDoListFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.list_container);

    //The codes below shows how to load fragments dynamically through Fragment Manager transaction
    //into the predefined frame container in the layout xml
    if(todoListFragment == null)


    {
        todoListFragment = new ToDoListFragment();

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.item_container, new NewItemFragment());
        ft.add(R.id.list_container, todoListFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }



    //Create the ArrayList of to do items
    todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Create the ArrayAdapter to bind the array to the List View


    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.todolist_item,todoItems);

    //Bind the Array Adapter to the List View
    todoListFragment.setListAdapter(aa);








}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onNewItemAdded(String newItem){
    todoItems.add(newItem);
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void onSwapButtonClicked (View view)
{
    //Get reference to the Fragments
            FragmentManager fm2 = getFragmentManager();
            ToDoListPlainFragment todoListFragment2 = new ToDoListPlainFragment();

            //The codes below shows how to load fragments dynamically through Fragment Manager transaction



                FragmentTransaction ft2 = fm2.beginTransaction();
                String myNewFragmentTag = null;
                ft2.replace(R.id.list_container, todoListFragment2,myNewFragmentTag);

                ft2.commit();






            //Create the ArrayAdapter to bind the array to the List View


            aa2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,todoItems);

            //Bind the Array Adapter to the List View
            todoListFragment2.setListAdapter(aa2);



}

}
```

[NewItemFragment.java]

```
package com.jiao.android.todolist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewItemFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_item_fragment,container,false);

    final EditText myEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

    //this is how an editText can respond to DPAD_CENTER
            //or the enter key
            myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)||
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
                        {
                           String newItem = myEditText.getText().toString();
                           onNewItemAddedListener.onNewItemAdded(newItem);
                           myEditText.setText("");


                           return true;

                        }

                    return false;
                }
            });

            return view;
}

public interface OnNewItemAddedListener {
    public void onNewItemAdded(String newItem);
}

private OnNewItemAddedListener onNewItemAddedListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try{
        onNewItemAddedListener = (OnNewItemAddedListener)activity;

    }catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+" must implement OnNewItemAddedListener");
    }
}

}
```

[MyTextView.java]

```
package com.jiao.android.todolist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyTextView extends TextView{




public MyTextView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context,attrs, defStyle);
    // do not forgot to call the ini() method, otherwise, allt he paint objects
    // won't be initialized
    init();
}

public MyTextView (Context context)
{
    super(context);
    // do not forgot to call the ini() method, otherwise, allt he paint objects
    // won't be initialized
    init();
}

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    // do not forgot to call the ini() method, otherwise, allt he paint objects
    // won't be initialized
    init();
}

private Paint marginPaint;
private Paint linePaint;
private int paperColor;
private float margin;

private void init(){
    //Get a referencve to our resource table
    Resources myResources = getResources();

    //Create the paint brushes we will use in the onDraw method.
    marginPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    marginPaint.setColor(myResources.getColor(R.color.notepad_margin));
    linePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    linePaint.setColor(myResources.getColor(R.color.notepad_lines));
    System.out.println("line paint is"+linePaint.getColor());

    //Get the paper background color and the margin width.
    paperColor = myResources.getColor(R.color.notepad_paper);
    margin = myResources.getDimension(R.dimen.notepad_margin);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){


    //Color as paper
    canvas.drawColor(paperColor);

    //Draw ruled lines
    //drawLine(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Paint paint) 
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0,0,  getMeasuredHeight(), linePaint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), linePaint);

    //Draw Margin
    canvas.drawLine(margin,0,margin,getMeasuredHeight(), marginPaint);

    //Move the text across from the margin
    canvas.save();
    //The translate() method remaps the (0,0) position on the canvas
    //or you can think you move the canvas
    //Translate - Basically do what it says. Just translate the canvas using x,y. 
    //If you want to draw two objects and the one is just translation of the other e.g x2 = x1 + 50 for each point . 
    //You don't have to make all your calculations again for the second object but you can just translate the canvas 
    //and draw again the same object. 
    canvas.translate(margin,0);
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //This call balances a previous call to save(), 
    //and is used to remove all modifications to the matrix/clip state since the last save call.
    //canvas.save and canvas.restore undo things like rotation and translation. They don't undo drawing on the canvas.
    canvas.restore();

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent){
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, keyEvent);
}


}
```

[ToDoListFragment.java]

```
package com.jiao.android.todolist;

import android.app.ListFragment;

 public class ToDoListFragment extends ListFragment {

 }
```

[ToDoListPlainFragment.java]

```
 package com.jiao.android.todolist;

 import android.app.ListFragment;

 public class ToDoListPlainFragment extends ListFragment {

 }
```

Below are the layout xml files:

[activity_main.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

 >
<LinearLayout 

android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/swapButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/swap_button_text" 
        android:onClick="onSwapButtonClicked" 
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />

</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/item_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/list_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />









</LinearLayout>
```

[new_item_fragment.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myEditText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/addItemHint"
android:contentDescription="@string/addItemContentDescription" />
```

[todolist_item.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.jiao.android.todolist.MyTextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textColor="@color/notepad_text"
android:fadingEdge="vertical" 
/>
```

Here is the [AndroidManifest.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jiao.android.todolist"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.jiao.android.todolist.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

You have given your `LinearLayout` **height** as `match_parent` so it will match the whole parent that's why FrameLayout is not showing. Give `LinearLayout` **height** as `wrap_content` and try it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  // change is here
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/swapButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:onClick="onSwapButtonClicked"
            android:text="swap_button_text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That resolved my issue. This issue seems to be a classic problem. And there is even a video talking about the difference between match_parent vs wrap_content.

Comment: There is the link to the video: http://dibbsolutions.com/tutorials/android-wrap-content-vs-match-parent/